# Using ADFS and SAML for querying AD with Java

Tags: java, saml, claims-based-identity, adfs

I need to query AD outside organizational boundaries from a Java application and get a list of users from that with proper authentication and privileges using ADFS and SAML.

I am new to ADFS and SAML and claim based authentication.  I need to use these technologies with JAVA.

How can I integrate ADFS with java in this scenario?

Comment: Are you looking to query AD to just get the list of authorized users?  (Essentially an LDAP query?)  Or are you looking to authenticate AD users to external applications? (More common scenario with SAML)

Comment: Thanks for your reply... Looking to query the AD to get list of Users...
Let me rephrase the requirement...

I want to query Active Directory which is behind/using ADFS to get List of users. in this case will there be any difference in querying the AD from the way we normally query AD using Java.

Answer (score 1):

ADFS doesn't offer a means to get "a list of users".  For that you should look at traditional ways of querying AD using LDAP (as proposed by Aaron).

As you point out - ADFS provides claims-based authentication features, via protocols such as SAML 2 and WS-Federation.  These protocols are typically used to get a security token for a user, and use that token to authenticate them at a Service Provider (external application).  This interaction would be done on a user initiated basis, with them first authenticating to ADFS (acting as the Identity Provider).

It's not clear to me what your entire project entails, but perhaps that approach could be applied?  If not - you may have to look at opening up firewall ports to access AD via LDAP (or LDAPS).

Comment: Thanks a Lot Sacott for your Inputs... If i make a call to AD via LDAP which is behind ADFS that should be seamless for me right?

Comment: Well, you wouldn't make the call through ADFS as it doesn't listen for LDAP requests.  You would make the call directly to AD (albeit likely through some firewalls).  Having ADFS in the picture shouldn't change anything.

Comment: Thanks Scott for your Clarification... I'll try and let you know the progress... :) ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good place to start: http://jeftek.com/222/using-java-code-with-active-directory/